# about text in android app.

Tags: android, string, layout

I have been prompt with warning about the text I using in the layout
below is one of the warnings:

```
[I18N] Hardcoded string "Application Examples line 427  Android Lint Problem
```

is that issue if I leave it as it as or should I change it?

what is the common / best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to support more than one language, you should not hard-code strings in your application.  You should use an approach that allows for your application to choose the language-appropriate string based on the current device settings.

The best practice is to externalize your strings into resource files.  This allows you to provide one resource file per locale that you wish to support (i.e. one for English, one for French, etc).

This practice is documented here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Answer (score 0):

In Android we should better to use @string resource which you can define res->values->strings.xml file.

This is useful because same string we can use multiple places and single change will effect everywhere and also useful for supporting multiple languages in future.

So you can define @string resource or just ignore the warning, not an issue.